# Custom object not displaying name of included custom object

Tags: custom-object, page-layout, fields, custom

I have a custom object named Notes (Notes__c) living within Opportunities.  Notes lets me put in a bunch of great information about my latest meeting, including a list of attendees.  I can include attendees from my org, plus include outside attendees that are custom objects (herein called homeys__c and homefries__c).  After I've added all the attendees, I can see the names of the attendees from my org, but the homeys and homefries names appear blank as in the image below:
[image: Where are the homeys, the homefries?!?!]

So it looks like (since I come from a database background) that I need some sort of UNION clause in order to get the names to show up under Attendee name.  What can I modify declaratively or programmatically to do so?

A hint might be data type for the homeys and homefries are lookups from the Contact field, and that org attendees are provided from the User field within SF.  The goal is to get the Attendees names to show for all attendees...

Comment: So 'Attendee Name' and 'Influencer' are both Lookup fields to Contact / User? If you view the AN-105 record while logged in as your user or Admin can you see the field values?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett 'Influencer' happens to be an optional field that can be filled in when creating or editing the attendee.  'Attendee Name' is a Lookup field, however it only displays the lookup from the 'User' field and I need to display both the User and the Contact depending on which group the Attendee belongs.

Comment: A lookup can only point to one object, polymorphic lookups would be nice but are not supported currently on custom fields. What I suggest is you have two fields Attendee User (lookup to User) and Attendee Contact (lookup to Contact), populate one accordingly and then have a 'Attendee' formula field (you can use in the UI, Reports, Dashboards etc) which resolves figures out which of these two fields contains a value and displays the name. Would that work for you?